# Deleting sheets from Excel using Visual Basic and Interop

Tags: excel, vb.net, office-interop

I have a subprogram which should delete sheets with a non-numeric name. It's finding the sheets but not deleting them. I can't figure out why....

It's not throwing errors and it's creating the PDF (with all sheets). If I set the `xlsBook.Close` to save changes the workbook still has all the sheets after the process runs.

I'm running this in **Visual Studio 2015** with **MSOffice 2013**. Here's the code snippet;

```
    Imports System
    Imports System.IO
    Imports Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel
    Imports Microsoft.Office.Interop.PowerPoint
    Imports Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word
    Imports Microsoft.Office.Core


    Private Sub Convert_Excel(ByVal InFormat As String, ByVal InSpecial As String)

    Dim xlsApp = New Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application()
    Dim xlsBook As Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Workbook
    Dim xlsSheet As Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Worksheet

    xlsApp.Application.DisplayAlerts = False

    Try
        xlsApp.ScreenUpdating = False
        xlsBook = xlsApp.Workbooks.Open(theFile, UpdateLinks:=False, ReadOnly:=False)
                    For Each xlsSheet In xlsBook.Sheets
                            If Not IsNumeric(xlsSheet.Name) Then
                                    Try
                                            xlsSheet.Delete()
                                    Catch ex As Exception
                                            Environment.ExitCode = ERROR_EXCEL_NOSHEETS
                                    End Try
                            End If
                    Next

        If xlsBook.Worksheets.Count > 1 And Environment.ExitCode <> ERROR_EXCEL_NOSHEETS Then
            If LCase(InFormat) = "standard" Then
                xlsBook.ExportAsFixedFormat(XlFixedFormatType.xlTypePDF, thePDFFile, XlFixedFormatQuality.xlQualityStandard,
                                            True, True, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, False, Type.Missing)
            Else
                Environment.ExitCode = ERROR_EXCEL_BADOP
                If Not Command_In Then
                    System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show("INVALID OPERATION SELECTED")
                End If
            End If
        End If
        xlsBook.Close(SaveChanges:=False)
        xlsApp.Quit()
        xlsBook = Nothing
        xlsApp = Nothing
        pdfnameLabel.Text = "Created " & Convert_FilePDF
    Catch ex As Exception
        Environment.ExitCode = ERROR_EXCEL_UNKNOWN
        If Not Command_In Then
            System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show(ex.Message)
        End If
    Finally
        If xlsBook IsNot Nothing Then
            xlsBook.Close(SaveChanges:=False)
        End If
        If xlsApp IsNot Nothing Then
            xlsApp.Quit()
        End If
    End Try

End Sub
```

Comment: Try working backwards from the last sheet: it's never a good idea to delete items from a collection while you're iterating over it using For Each

Comment: @TimWilliams In a (probably) unrelated note, I would suggest creating a list of the worksheets to delete: `Dim sheetsToDelete = xlBook.Sheets.Cast(Of Worksheet).Where(Function(x) Not IsNumeric(x.Name)).ToList`. Then you could safely delete all the worksheets in that list without worrying about the iteration collection, and it would also be trivial to check if the length of the list is greater than the count of all worksheets in the workbook.

Comment: What happens if you remove the `Try..Catch` from within the `If Not IsNumeric(xlSheet.Name) Then` block?

Comment: Also, can you follow this step by step with the debugger, and see when it's doing something unusual?

Comment: Remove the try-catch did nothing.  FYI - it was in there in case all the sheet were non numeric and resulted in an empty file.  Line by line debugging shows nothing.  Please note it's not deleting anything.  I can try working backwards but I would have thought that out of a 4 sheet workbook with 2 bad sheets I would end up with a PDF of the two sheets.  Granted they might not have been the ones I wanted but *something* would have been deleted.....

Answer (score 1):

Now, for what @TimWilliams has said. I am not sure why you don't get error here-you should at some point

```
For Each xlsSheet In xlsBook.Sheets
    If Not IsNumeric(xlsSheet.Name) Then
        Try
            xlsSheet.Delete() ' <-- should error here
        . . . . . . . .
```

You should use While-loop for mutating collections.

```
Dim index as Integer
While index < xlsBook.Sheets.Count -1
    . . . . . . . 
    ' here, when you remove Sheets(index), don't increment it 
    ' because next sheet will now have this index.
    ' NOTE, I am not sure if sheets it 0 or 1-based collection
```

In truth, until you change your for-loop to while-loop, it will be unclear where exactly the issue.

**Update**
After some going back and forth it seem that you need [before delete] to add

```
xlsApp.Application.DisplayAlerts = False
```

Comment: I'm not trying to save the workbook.  just delete the sheets and export it out as a PDF.  I'm not using indices.  I thought since the xlsSheet was an actual Worksheet with a delete method it would delete.

Comment: @wrkoch Ok. Fine. It would delete but then `xlsBook.Sheets` collection is mutated and enumerator that it generated for `for-loop` is no longer valid

Comment: I see where you are going with that.  I'll give it a go.

Comment: Sigh.  no luck. yet.  I went back to basics and set the code like this:

Comment: @wrkoch I didn't understand your message 100%. Have you added `while- loop`, debugged through it, it deleted something, you have different count of sheets before print than in the beginning, there was no entry into `catch`, and you printing and still getting sheets that you supposedly  deleted? did your code actually matched condition `If Not IsNumeric(xlsSheet.Name) Then` ?

Comment: Sigh.  no luck. yet.  I went back to basics and set the code like this:

xlsBook = xlsApp.Workbooks.Open(Convert_File.FullName, UpdateLinks:=False, ReadOnly:=False)
xlsSheet = xlsBook.Sheets(1)
xlsSheet.Delete()
xlsBook.ExportAsFixedFormat(XlFixedFormatType.xlTypePDF, Convert_FilePDF, XlFixedFormatQuality.xlQualityStandard,
              True, True, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, False, Type.Missing)

xlsBook.Close(SaveChanges:=True)

It didn't delete sheet 1 in the PDF or the saved workbook. I don't understand this.

Comment: sorry forgot to indent
`
      xlsBook = xlsApp.Workbooks.Open(Convert_File.FullName, UpdateLinks:=False, ReadOnly:=False)
      xlsSheet = xlsBook.Sheets(1)
      xlsSheet.Delete()
      xlsBook.ExportAsFixedFormat(XlFixedFormatType.xlTypePDF, Convert_FilePDF, XlFixedFormatQuality.xlQualityStandard,
                True, True, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, False, Type.Missing)

      xlsBook.Close(SaveChanges:=True)

`

Comment: @wrkoch may be your answer is here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16436654/cant-delete-sheet

Comment: not sure how to capture that.  Delete() says it doesn't produce a result

Comment: @wrkoch Ok, it is different then

Comment: @wrkoch looks like you definitely should do this xlApp.DisplayAlerts = false 
worksheet.Delete() 
xlApp.DisplayAlerts = true

Comment: it deleted sheet 1.  I had  xlsApp.Application.DisplayAlerts = False.  Now that I know it can delete I can get this to work.  Thank You!!!